# I am using Modals in my Create user view but it doesn't pop up

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, crud

.when i click on the button,it doesn't open the modal.but it works in update view only.i have tried different modals codes, but again it only works in update view.
i put them in both different and same sections and /or dive, it didn't work.
here is one of the code i have tried:

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="card-title">
                            <h5 class="mb-0">select Master</h5>
                        </div>
                        <hr />
                        <div class="row row-cols-auto g-3">
                            <div class="col">
                                <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal"
                                        data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
                                 select Master
                                </button>
                                <!-- Modal -->
                                <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1"
                                     aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                                        <div class="modal-content">
                                            <div class="modal-header">
                                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Select Master</h5>
                                                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                                                        aria-label="Close"></button>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-body">
                                               lorem ipsum
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"
                                                        data-bs-dismiss="modal">
                                                    close
                                                </button>
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                                                    save changes
                                                </button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you using `asp.net` or are you using `asp.net-core`?

Comment: I have tried it and it works fine. I think you need to provide the code which can help us to reproduce it. I mean problematic View and controller methods, we need to investigate this issue further.

Comment: From the current description, it seems that there are some js files or css files in the problematic page, which prevents this pop-up window. You can narrow down the scope by annotating other js or css files.

Comment: _@JasonPan  i comment my admin layout which i used in my view, the modal worked.(however i use this layout  for the "update" view  which modal works properly). and i comment all scripts and links to try the modal in a blank page, it didnt work in create view :(

Comment: @M.H.D If you can share your sample project without any sensitive info, we can help you faster.